# Using share function with Site Groups

Tags: document

When we share a file with someone in SharePoint 2013, the user will receive an email generally.

I have observed that when we put a sharepoint group rather than a single user in the sharing pane, the email doesn't go to everyone in the group.

Can we configure it so that an email is sent out to everyone in the group? In other words to entire group.